# Android xmpp error host-unknown

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack

I'm trying to make a connection to xmpp server and this returning me this error.

> W/AbstractXMPPConnection: Connection closed with error
>        org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$StreamErrorException: host-unknown You can read more about the meaning of this stream error
>   at http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#streams-error-conditions
>        
>            at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1003)
>            at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPConnection.java:944)
>            at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:959)
>            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

I tried to use this example in [github](https://github.com/axcl/SMACK-API-Android-Demo) and put this data.

```
private static final String DOMAIN = "10.20.0.125"; 

private static final String HOST = "10.20.0.125"; 

private static final int PORT = 5222;

private String userName ="admin2@localhost";

private String passWord = "asdfasdf";
```

The server is ok, we conducted another test pc to make a communication on android but this error persists.

Answer (score 0):

I see mainly 2 errors:

in the demo configuration you have this lines of code:

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
    configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword(userName, passWord);
    configBuilder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
    configBuilder.setResource("Android");
    configBuilder.setServiceName(DOMAIN);
    configBuilder.setHost(HOST);
    configBuilder.setPort(PORT);
```

First problem (main one):
DOMAIN variable SHOULD (but MUST) BE the server name you can read in server configuration, not just the IP; some functionality will broke outside the localhost.

Second problem:
while I suggest to split login from configuration (so just configure the connection and THEN login) what I don't get it's the username: **localhost** will be not resolved outside the server machine, so again **has to be replaced with DOMAIN name** (even if, in theory, the connection will give the user his domain, doesn't need to be so explicit).

so:

```
 connection.connect();
 login();
```

will be replaced with

```
 connection.connect();
 login(userName ,passWord,"Android" );
```

and you'll need to remove this 2 lines:

```
configBuilder.setResource("Android");
configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword(userName, passWord);
```

**about DOMAIN name**: you'll find it in Server configuration, in Openfire it's the "Server Name" you can read in web interface in Server Information page.

Comment: I made the necessary changes but I am with the following error when performing the connection.login (LoginUser, passwordUser, RESOURCE_TYPE): login: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'byte[] org.jivesoftware.smack.util.stringencoder.Base64$Encoder.encode(byte[], int, int)' on a null object reference

Comment: What's the value of "RESOURCE_TYPE" ? Did you register your user on the server? However i think it's another question...

Comment: I do not think a new ticket is required. Because this error arose in the implementation of the amendments provided! But RESOURCE_TYPE is specified (such as "Android"), just in case removed to make a new test in the login and the problem persists.

Comment: as you wish but it's hard, at least for me, to follow up with a code that's no more the one in original question and a new stacktrace you haven't full pasted.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution.
I was using .jar files instead of the compile gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.4'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.4'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.4'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.4'
```

Thus the error has been resolved. Thank you for your help.